# "Error injecting constructor" when mapping Enumeration using Slick 3.1 with play and scala

Tags: scala, playframework, guice, slick

I have the following classes. please note the commented-out Role lines.

user model:

```
case class User(
  uid: Option[Long] = None,
//  role: Option[Role.Role] = None,
  firstName: String,
  lastName: String,
  middleName: Option[String] = None,
  email: String,
  avatarUrl: Option[String],
  created: DateTime = DateTime.now,
  modified: DateTime = DateTime.now
)
```

UserComponent and UserDAO:

```
import javax.inject._
import scala.concurrent.Future
import org.krazykat.whatsupdoc.models.User
import play.api.db.slick.{HasDatabaseConfigProvider, DatabaseConfigProvider}
import play.api.libs.concurrent.Execution.Implicits.defaultContext
import slick.driver.{JdbcProfile, JdbcDriver}
import org.joda.time.DateTime
import com.github.tototoshi.slick.GenericJodaSupport
import java.sql.Time

trait UsersComponent { self: HasDatabaseConfigProvider[JdbcProfile]  =>
  import driver.api._

  object PortableJodaSupport extends GenericJodaSupport(driver.asInstanceOf[JdbcDriver])
  import PortableJodaSupport._


//  implicit val roleMapper = MappedColumnType.base[Role.Role, String](
//    e => e.toString,
//    s => Role.withName(s)
//  )


  class Users(tag: Tag) extends Table[User](tag, "USERS") {

    def uid = column[Long]("USER_ID", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)
//    def role = column[Role.Role]("ROLE") 
    def firstName = column[String]("FIRST_NAME")
    def lastName = column[String]("LAST_NAME")
    def middleName = column[String]("MIDDLE_NAME")
    def email = column[String]("EMAIL")
    def avatarUrl = column[String]("AVATAR_URL")
    def created =  column[DateTime]("CREATED")
    def modified = column[DateTime]("MODIFIED")

    def * = (uid.?, firstName, lastName, middleName.?, email, avatarUrl.?, created, modified) <> (User.tupled, User.unapply _)
  }
}


/**
 * @author ehud
 */
@Singleton
class UsersDAO @Inject()(protected val dbConfigProvider: DatabaseConfigProvider) extends UsersComponent with HasDatabaseConfigProvider[JdbcProfile] {
  import driver.api._

  val users = TableQuery[Users]

  def count = db.run(users.length.result)

  def getById(uid: Long) = 
    db.run(users.filter(_.uid === uid).result.headOption)

  def insert(user: User) =
    db.run((users returning users.map(_.uid)) += user).map(id => id)

  def delete(user: User) =
    db.run(users.filter(_.uid === user.uid).delete)

  def update(uid: Long, user: User) = {
    val userToUpdate: User = user.copy(Some(uid))
    db.run(users.filter(_.uid === uid).update(userToUpdate))
  }
}
```

and a test spec:

```
class UsersSpec extends Specification {


  def dateIs(date: java.util.Date, str: String) = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(date) == str

  trait WithDatabaseConfig {
    lazy val (driver, db) = {
      val dbConfig = DatabaseConfigProvider.get[JdbcProfile](Play.current)
      (dbConfig.driver, dbConfig.db)
    }
  }

  "User model" should {   
    def usersDao(implicit app: Application) = {
      val app2UsersDAO = Application.instanceCache[UsersDAO]
      app2UsersDAO(app)
    }

    "be inserted to db correctly" in new WithApplication with WithDatabaseConfig {
      import driver.api._

      val userInsertresult = Await.result(usersDao.insert(
        User(None, "firstname", "lastname", Some("middlename"), "me@me.com", Some("avatar"), DateTime.now, DateTime.now)), 
        Duration.Inf
      )
      val count = Await.result(usersDao.count, Duration.Inf)
      count mustEqual 1
    }
```

when i run this spec, it succeeds. great.

now i want to add a role to my user. so i created the following Role class:

```
object Role extends Enumeration{

  type Role = Value

  val None = Value("NONE")
  val Admin = Value("ADMIN")
  val Root = Value("ROOT")
}
```

and uncomment the relevant lines (and add it to any instanciation call), and update the evolutions file (the Role part is stored as a VARCHAR). now, when the spec runs, i get the following exception:

```
[error]   ! be inserted to db correctly
[error]    Unable to provision, see the following errors:
[error]    
[error]    1) Error injecting constructor, java.lang.NullPointerException
[error]      at UsersDAO.<init>(UsersDAO.scala:59)
[error]      at UsersDAO.class(UsersDAO.scala:59)
[error]      while locating UsersDAO
[error]    
[error]    1 error (InjectorImpl.java:1025)
[error] com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2.get(InjectorImpl.java:1025)
[error] com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInstance(InjectorImpl.java:1051)
[error] play.api.inject.guice.GuiceInjector.instanceOf(GuiceInjectorBuilder.scala:321)
[error] play.api.inject.guice.GuiceInjector.instanceOf(GuiceInjectorBuilder.scala:316)
[error] play.api.Application$$anonfun$instanceCache$1.apply(Application.scala:234)
[error] play.api.Application$$anonfun$instanceCache$1.apply(Application.scala:234)
[error] play.utils.InlineCache.fresh(InlineCache.scala:69)
[error] play.utils.InlineCache.apply(InlineCache.scala:55)
```

I tried researching online, but all the Slick samples I found on how to do Enumerations seem like mine, and the injection error does not show up in the Slick context.

any idea?

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that you are trying to use `driver.api.MappedColumnType` from the `HasDatabaseConfigProvider` trait in the `UsersComponent` trait.
But at the moment of the `UsersComponent` initialization driver is not injected yet, that causes NPE.
You can either make your `roleMapper` val `lazy` or change it from `val` to `def`:

```
implicit lazy val roleMapper = ...
```

OR

```
implicit def roleMapper = ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Any particular reason you go for `Enumeration`? I can't help you if so, but I can suggest using sealed trait + case objects + [sealerate](https://github.com/mrvisser/sealerate).

Create a companion for `case class User` and describe `Role`

```
object User {
  sealed trait Role
  case object None extends Role
  case object Root extends Role
  case object Admin extends Role

  // A bit messy stuff to convert Role to String and back
  def s = sealerate.values[Role].foldLeft(Map[String, Role]()) { case (m, f) ⇒ m.updated(f.toString, f) }
  implicit val roleColumnType: JdbcType[Role] with BaseTypedType[Role] = MappedColumnType.base[Role, String](_.toString, s)
}
```

Add `role` to `User` case class

```
case class User(
  uid: Option[Long] = None,
  role: Option[User.Role] = User.None,
  firstName: String,
  lastName: String,
  middleName: Option[String] = None,
  email: String,
  avatarUrl: Option[String],
  created: DateTime = DateTime.now,
  modified: DateTime = DateTime.now
)
```

Add `role` to `Users` table

```
class Users(tag: Tag) extends Table[User](tag, "USERS") {
  ...
  def role = column[User.Role]("ROLE") 
  ...
}
```

That's all :)

Brief explanation on Scala enums [here](http://underscore.io/blog/posts/2014/09/03/enumerations.html).

Comment: that works great, except for one thing - the UserComponent uses the generic jdbc driver (trait UsersComponent { self: HasDatabaseConfigProvider[JdbcProfile] =>) and the DAO is injecting the dBConfigProvidor (see above). all this so i can release the dependency on the specific DB driver. 

the problem is MappedColumnType.base[Role, String] is part of the jdbc driver, so i need to make that generic as well. any thoughts?

Comment: Not sure about this, I've only used specific driver. I can see both `HasDatabaseConfigProvider` and `MappedColumnType` being used [here](https://github.com/tminglei/slick-pg/blob/master/examples/play-slick-example/app/dao/ComputersDAO.scala). Does that help somehow?